What are possible materials for clothes in a world without a history?
Clothes can be made in a number of ways, beginning with fabric, or for the purposes of this question, flexible material. But clothing doesn't have to be made of flexible material and could, instead, be partially or, in some cases, totally rigid. There are two purposes of clothes that must be met, however: Protection from the elements, and common decency. Both must be served to some degree for clothing to be considered "practical."
For clothes to made of a material, the material needs to be accessible, and for our purposes, at least semi-renewable. That being said, it needs a clear origin.
If you would, share ideas as to what materials could potentially be used to make clothes in a nondescript fantasy world -- whatever sort of fantasy world you want it to be -- and where it comes from.

Is there a specific world building question? If you were to provide the details of the world you’re working in that would be better; in fantasy settings, literally anything goes without some sort of restriction.

Possible materials are many, and this site does not really accept questions where the answer would be a long list. For example, here on Earth we make clothes out of grass, hemp. straw, bamboo, cotton, flax, jute, banana, bamboo, lotus, eucalyptus, mulberry, sugarcane, wool (obtained from many different species), silk, paper, rayon, modal, diacetate fibers, triacetate fibers, nylon, modacrylic, olefin, acrylic fibers, polyester, polyurethane, rubber ... And those are just the most common.

It's worth putting in a bit of your own research before asking so that you can ask a more specific question.

Fig leaves? But more to the point, the [tour] states that Stack Exchange isn't a discussion forum, the [help/dont-ask] discourages brainstorming and the [help/dont-ask] prohibits questions where every answer has equal value. I'd vote to reopen if you can [edit] the question to explain how you'd select a single best answer.

History says this is a non-issue
In our own world, clothing has been around since about 100,000 to 500,000 years ago which is LONG before the origins of written or even painted history.  Pretty much every place in the world has at least one native fibrous plant that is appropriate for making woven cloth whether that be cotton, jute, flax, hemp, nettle, etc.  Even if you don't have access to this, there are animal skins which are much less labor intensive to turn into basic clothing.  And even more simple than this would be shirts and skirts made of bunched and woven grasses.
If you want inspiration for just how much is possible, I suggest looking up the clothing styles of the stone ages societies that still exist today of which there are various Native American, African, and Aboriginal tribal societies that still practice making their own cloth from local plants and animals which they learn how to do through their oral tradition.
But Because this is a Fantasy Setting, it does raise the question about there being even better materials
There are many mythical and fantasy plants and beasts that are said to have a wide range of unique properties that could make them particularly good for clothing.

The Nieman Lion had an uncuttable hide; so, if you could shape its hide with magic, you could use it as a super material for thing like work boots and gloves.
Alligator leather was such a hot commodity in Colonial America that alligators were nearly hunted to extinction, but perhaps hydra leather would make a super cheap and renewable alternative sense its heads grow back so quickly.
Vulcani leather is immune to flames making it favored among blacksmiths.
Aglaophotis cloth for warding off demons and witchcraft
Raskovnik cloth might be favored among criminals to aid in their burguary and to evade imprisonment
Hithlain cloth is of course perfect for camouflage in any environment.
Any other fantasy or magical qualities you want, just make something up and give the plant or animal it comes from a good backstory, and its just as good as taking from existing lore.


Yeah. That's kind of the point. Obscure and weird real life fabrics, as well as ideas on how else fabric might be made, in a fictional world.

"of which there are various Native American" .. I presume you're thinking of the 'lost' tribes still found in the amazon rainforest? .. rightly or wrongly people do tend to associate "American" with the US, I'd suggest saying South American or The Amazon to avoid confusion in the minds of some and lend a bit more clarity to what you mean.

note: "Even if you don't have access to this (woven cloth), there are animal skins which are much less labor intensive to turn into basic clothing. " This is only true on the lower end of the economics of scale, for a civilization more advanced than say, Early Bronze Age, the relationship is inverted. For leather clothing, the bottleneck is the number of animals, which can only be increased with animal husbandry, which is very labor intensive. The bottleneck of cloth making is spinning thread, which can be improved a dozen-fold with some simple devices.

@GoingDurden That is a good point.  But since the OP said "In a world without History", I assumed this to mean a pre-historical society.

@Pelinore Yes, there are the lost tribes of Amazon, but there are also many North American tribes that still mostly wear traditional, handmade clothing.  The Inuits for example typically prefer their hand-made Caribou Parkas over coats made of modern synthetic materials.  There are also many tribes in the United States itself where traditional styles and methods have been preserved out of a pure desire to resist industrial influences; so, I kept it broad on purpose by saying "various Native American"... while also trying not to imply that that is how all Native Americans still live.

@Nosajimiki "but there are also many North American tribes" those are not normally lumped in with "stone age societies" surely? metallurgy (with copper if not iron) was a thing in the americas long before europeans arrived .. here let me go look for a link for you .. here > North America Old Copper Culture? .. you really have to get into the Amazon before you're truly into stone age societies even before Europeans arrived I think?

@Pelinore Some copper working existed in the Americas before colonialism, but it was not ubiquitous.  Most Native American tribes used tools and weapons made of wood, bone, and stone.  Even those with some copper tools like the Aztecs still mostly used stone tools and weapons; so, the tech they used regularly was still mostly stone aged.  Most Native American civilizations were Neolithic or Mesolithic, with only a few actually being Chalcolithic.  As for iron, no native American civilization knew how to smelt iron.  What iron they did have was meteoric iron or acquired from foreign sources.

@Nosajimiki fair enough I suppose, 'most' of the copper use seemingly was more decorative than for tools? the iron doesn't count as that's the next age on :) and they didn't have it, dunno about meteoric iron but there was some re-working of 'found' iron, mostly what arrived on drift wood from wrecks wasn't it? and that doesn't count as they're not smelting it themselves anyway merely working it the same you would a bit of flint or antler or whatever.

@Pelinore I don't remember the exact tribe, but iirc, there was one in Canada that was near a large meteor impact site that had lots of exposed naturally occurring iron; so, they made themselves relatively high quality iron tools despite being a hunter-gatherer society.

@Nosajimiki The Inuit (Eskimos to most of us old farts) .. you got more than enough there for a search string ;) "canada meteorite iron indians" 1st result Cape York meteorite I'm guessing that's a strong contender for what you remember.

@Nosajimiki, yeah, the whole "world without history" is strange to me. History "starts" when stories are first preserved, but technology and civilization can be much older. You could have an Iron Age civilization without history, if they lived day-by-day, and produced no writing, paintings, oral traditions or art.

@Pelinore Yes, I think that was it.

To get those gears turning let's start with an extremely wierd and unconventional one: The gooey saliva or barf of a worm.
(China actually used this!)
I looked it up online what really weird real fabrics there are:
Pineapple Leather
Slime (from a fish)
Papier machete
A protein found in milk
Silk from animals besides silk worms.

Good answers have sources and links. Add the source of your research here .

You mean papier-mâché? I have never heard of clothes made of papier-mâché; and don' really see how it could be used for this purpose.

@AlexP I actually have. You usually get the cloth to hold it together at the joints and then you can get some sort of paper/leather/cloth and papier-mache it into something much firmer. It doesn't work very well, though, and it dissolves in water pretty quick.

Paper mache used to be a common ingredient of (extremely terrifying and nightmare inducing) children's Hallowe'en costumes early in the last century.

On the other hand, paper machetes could be very interesting indeed!

"old newspapers." That's what papier mache is, right? Glue and old newspapers.
